# How can I print in which column number and line number where pattern has been not matched

Tags: java, regex, expression

How can I print in which column number and line number where pattern of regular expression has been not matched.

My current code :

```
 reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(credentialPath));

 Pattern pattern = Pattern
                .compile(ApplicationLiterals.CREDENTIALS_URL_REG_EX);
 String line;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line.trim());
      if (matcher.find()) {
            // System.out.println(matcher.group());
            // System.out.println("**" + matcher.start());
            // System.out.println("***" + matcher.end());
            result = true;
            count1++;
       } else {
            // count1++;
            result = false;
            // System.out.println(matcher.group());
            // System.out.println(matcher.start());
            System.out.println("****problem at line number" + count1);
            break;
       }
  }
```

Comment: so what's the problem you're facing in doing this?

Comment: i am not able to print exact location where the content is not matched.

Comment: what error is it throwing? If not any error, what is the faulty output?

Comment: it is throwing illegal state exception when i am trying to print start end or group methods

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting a `IllegalStateException` is `matcher.group()` or `matcher.start()`.

Its pretty obvious that if the control goes to the `else` block, it means that the `line` does not match the `Pattern`. When there is no match found, how can you try to print the `start` or the `group` of that match?

The exception stack trace will clearly say this:- **No match found**.

If you see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29):-

> Throws:
>       IllegalStateException - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed

In your case too, since the match has failed, its throwing the `IllegalStateException`.

As you've already done, keep the `matcher.group()` & `matcher.start()` commented, uncomment the `count1++` and just print the `count1`. It'll give you the line number.

**Update:-**

Have this as your `else` block.

```
else {
    count1++;
    result = false;
    System.out.println("**This line doesn't match the pattern*** "+line);
    System.out.println("****problem at line number" + count1);
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro but this one i know i just want to know that if any pattern is not matched just i want to show to the user in this particular place your pattern is not matched. can we do this?

Comment: You can print that `line` itself to say that this line doesn't match the pattern. You can't pin point a particular column in the whole line, where the pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the show the pattern which  is not matched then you have two thing can do.

1.create a opposite pattern of the regular expression and in else block match it and show the exact word. for example if you have a regular expression like `[aeiou]*` then opposite will be `[^aeiou]*`.

2.Keep the `matcher.start() and matcher.end()` with same variable and in else block use those variable to find the rest part of the line where unmatched occur. suppose if your end 20 and in next iteration of loop it come to else block that means there is unmatched after 20 so show the content of line after 20.

EDIT:

Take help from flowing code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "Java is best \n Test Java is good \n  Java Hello";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Java");
    Matcher matcher = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
    String line = null;
    int end = 0;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        ++lineNumber;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            end = matcher.end();
        }
        if (end < line.length() - 1) {
            System.out.println("NOt matched Line :" + lineNumber + " Words:-"
                    + line.substring(end));
        }
    }
}
```